# Twisted DTPFactory timeout

Tags: python, ftp, twisted

I'm trying to setup a simple FTP server with twisted:

```
sudo venv/bin/twistd ftp -p 21 -r /home/ftpuser/ftproot/ --auth file:/home/ftpuser/pass.dat
```

When I run this from my Mac, it works perfectly. But I'm getting this error when running twisted FTP on an ubuntu box. Any idea what might be causing it?

```
[twisted.scripts._twistd_unix.UnixAppLogger#info] reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
[-] FTPFactory starting on 21
[twisted.protocols.ftp.FTPFactory#info] Starting factory <twisted.protocols.ftp.FTPFactory instance at 0x7f5d31173f80>
[FTP (ProtocolWrapper),0,100.35.194.233] DTPFactory.setTimeout set to 10 seconds
[FTP (ProtocolWrapper),0,100.35.194.233] DTPFactory starting on 38688
[twisted.protocols.ftp.DTPFactory#info] Starting factory <twisted.protocols.ftp.DTPFactory instance at 0x7f5d311712d8>
[-] timed out waiting for DTP connection
[-] Unexpected FTP error
[-] Unhandled Error
    Traceback (most recent call last):
    Failure: twisted.protocols.ftp.PortConnectionError: DTPFactory timeout
```